# nodes; user download via remote fileserver

Tags: node.js, download, fileserver

[image: browser request - webserver - fileserver (only access from webserver ip) - webserver - browser download]

I have a webserver and a fileserver. The webserver is allowed to access the fileserver (ip filter). I would like to share a file/make it downloadable from the fileserver, but without having to make a public access on the fileserver.
I'm thinking about making a api on the fileserver (small webserver)

```
router.get('/download', async (req, res) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://testserver");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-requested-With");
    res.download(__dirname + '/../download/'+req.query.file, req.query.file)
})
```

And then download the file via the webserver and then send it to the browser/user

```
router('/downloadOnTheWebserver', (req,res) => {
...
res.download(request('testserver' + someFileToDownload').pipe(make a downloadstream somehow))
```

Is that the way to do this, and how...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did this:

Fileserver:

```
router.get('/download', async (req, res) => { 
res.download(__dirname + '/folder/filename')
```

})

Webserver:

```
var pdfstream = request.get("https://downloadlinkonfileserver)
res.attachment('filename'); 
pdfstream.pipe(res)
res.on('finish',function (err,data){
  if(err){
    throw err
  } else {
    console.log('It went well');
}
```